# Piping results from on Powershell result to another

Tags: powershell

I am trying to debug a powershell script from another developer.  This is running Powershell 5.1.16299.251  Here is the line of code that is giving me problems (shown by -->):

```
 $CurrentProfile = $profile
$ConcourseSettings = Get-ChildItem $PSSessionRoot\Audatex.B2B.ConcourseUtilities.*\content\scripts\ConcourseSettings.ps1 -File

    if($ConcourseSettings)
    {
        $ConcourseNugetPackage = Get-Item $PSSessionRoot\Audatex.B2B.ConcourseUtilities.*\content* 
   -->  $ConcourseScriptsPath = $ConcourseNugetPackage | Get-Item -Path scripts 
        $ConcourseProjectTemplatesDir = "$ConcourseNugetPackage\dotnet" | Get-ChildItem -Filter templates 
        $GitIgnoreFile = "$ConcourseNugetPackage\dotnet" | Get-ChildItem -Filter gitignore -File

        & $ConcourseSettings    
    }
```

If I look at the $ConsourseSettings variable with test-path it does show true, so I know that it is getting that file.  It's the next line that I get this error:

> Get-Item : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pipeline an object which can be converted to file name string to `Get-Item`, or you can specify the `-Path` parameter. But you can't do both, that's why you got the error. PowerShell can't possibly know which value to use.

I suppose you are trying to assign the path of the directory of `$ConcourseNugetPackage` file to `$ConcourseScriptsPath`. Do it like this:

```
$ConcourseScriptsPath = $ConcourseNugetPackage.DirectoryName
```